# How can I get an HTML Canvas element that you can draw on to responsively fill it's parent element?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bootstrap-5

trouble trying to get the canvas to resize responsively.  So far the closest I've gotten is a canvas that will automatically fill the width of it's container, but for some reason not it's height.

I'm using this code to try and make the canvas responsive:

```
// Listens for resize event and calls setCanvasSize function
window.addEventListener('resize', setCanvasSize, false);

// helper function to remove "px" from size values below
function pxToNum(pxValue) {
  return parseFloat(pxValue.replace("px", ""))
}

// Function to set canvas dimensions dynamically, gets called when game is started and canvas is un-hidden
function setCanvasSize() {
  const parentStyles = window.getComputedStyle(canvas.parentElement)
  console.log(parentStyles)
  // Get the pixel width and height of the canvas's container
  const containerWidth = pxToNum(parentStyles.getPropertyValue("width"))
  const containerHeight = pxToNum(parentStyles.getPropertyValue("height"))
  console.log(containerHeight, containerWidth)

  // Set canvas dimensions to match the container size
  canvas.width = containerWidth;
  canvas.height = containerHeight;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap for the styling so I'm wondering if somehow some styling somewhere is conflicting with what I want, but I've tried adding `h-100` classes to the container and every single parent element it's within all the way up to `<html>` and I still can't make this thing vertically fill unless I hard code in a pixel value for height or set `canvas.height = window.innerHeight`, which unfortunately doesn't line up with the rest of my styles the way I want.

Comment: Could you make the code a bit more complete please by adding some HTML. If you could use the [Code Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) functionality, that would be ideal.

Comment: Setting the canvas width and height changes the resolution of the canvas. The display size (which is independent of resolution) may not change (depending on CSS rules) when the resolution is changed. Set the display size via the canvas elements' style property... Example at the bottom of the function `setCanvasSize`, add the lines`canvas.style.width = containerWidth + "px"; canvas.style.height = containerHeight + "px";`